# Strange gfortran compilation error when adding Openmp directives

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have legacy fortran source file named pot.f, 
which I need to apply OpenMP to parallel as shown below,but I can error messages about unexpected end state etc. But when I comment out `$OMP` lines by adding additional ! in the first column, there are not errors.

It is really weird to me. Can anybody tell me what went wrong?

```
subroutine pot_osc(rvp,R_pot,e_pot,pe_pot,ftmp,gtmp,vtmp,natoms)
   implicit none
   include 'sizes.h'
   include 'constants.h'
   include 'omp_lib.h'

   double precision  ftmp(maxatoms,3),gtmp(3),R_pot(maxatoms,3)

   !$OMP PARALLEL WORKSHARE  SHARED(gtmp,ftmp)
   !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(16)
      gtmp = 0d0
      ftmp = 0d0
   !$OMP END PARALLEL WORKSHARE 
   return
end

subroutine pot_asym(rvp,vtmp)
   implicit none
   include 'constants.h'  
   return
end
```

Error messages:

```
 end
   1

Error: Unexpected END statement at (1)


  subroutine pot_asym(rvp,vtmp)
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Comment: I noticed you used `maxatoms` as first index in your arrays. My guess would be that you described three-dimensional vectors associated with each atom. I think it would be better to transpose those arrays as Fortran is [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order). That way, the 3D vectors would be contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 6):

You start a second `parallel` section in the second OpenMP directive, which is not terminated by an `end parallel`. So the OpenMP directive should read

```
!$OMP PARALLEL WORKSHARE SHARED(gtmp,ftmp) NUM_THREADS(16)
       gtmp = 0d0
       ftmp = 0d0
!$OMP END PARALLEL WORKSHARE
```

or if you like to keep the line break use

```
!$OMP PARALLEL WORKSHARE SHARED(gtmp,ftmp) &
!$OMP NUM_THREADS(16)
       gtmp = 0d0
       ftmp = 0d0
!$OMP END PARALLEL WORKSHARE
```

In the past, I experienced some problems with exactly this kind of initialization. It seems that when compiled with `gfortran` the master thread did all the work. Even worse, by means of the "first-stouch principle", the whole array was located in the memory associated with the first thread. On our CCNUMA machine this lead to a huge slowdown.

To solve this I used explicit loops to initialize:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(gtmp,ftmp) NUM_THREADS(16)
       do i=1,maxatoms
         ftmp(i,:) = 0d0
       enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
!      No need to do three elements in parallel
       gtmp = 0d0
```

I don't know whether they fixed this problem, but I use this way of initialization for arrays in shared memory since then.

Comment: The array assignments inside `WORKSHARE` are parallelised by `gfortran` if the array sections syntax is used instead, e.g. `gtmp(:) = 0.d0; ftmp(:,:) = 0.d0`. Otherwise all the work is done in a `SINGLE` directive.

Comment: IIRC, at least in my gfortran 4.8, you an use also whole arrays.

Comment: thanks for the answer! intel syntax doesn't compatible with mpif90 when break line.